# What happens if we run out of terrain tiles?

Tags: terra-mystica

In a recent game we almost ran out of a particular terrain tile.

In this scenario, what do you do? Is substituting a different token and remembering the terrain type allowed, or is the terraform not allowed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The rules don't specify what happens, but Helge Ostertag, one of the designers for Terra Mystica answered in [this thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/article/12254432#12254432) on Board Game Geek that yes, the terrain tiles are meant to be unlimited, so if you run out of terrain tiles you are still allowed to terraform.

Answer (score 3):

The terrain tiles are two-sided with different combinations, so when you run short of one type, often you should be able to replace ones already placed by others with the same front but different back side.
For example you are short of desert. Probably you have some forrest/desert already placed on the board as forrest. Try to find them and replace them by forrest/mountain to have one more desert available.